# sql statement explanation correct or not

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT max(orderNo) as maxno FROM orders
```

does this return maximum value for order number and stores it in a new column called maxno

Comment: No, it is just an [alias](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp)

Comment: so i would say it just renames the column to maxno and my return explanation is that right